# Is this the Potential energy of the system or of the proton?

Tags: electrostatics, charge, potential-energy

Lets suppose a proton is brought from infinity towards another proton which is fixed, now we can easily calculate the Work done by the external force and we can calculate the potential energy of the proton by question was that is this the potential energy of the system or only of the proton and please give a reason.

Comment: What do you mean by “potential energy of the system”?

Comment: The question could use some rephrasing, I request for an edit to make the question clear. (eg. what is that “by question”?)

Answer (score 0):

> was that is this the potential energy of the system or only of the proton and please give a reason.

This potential energy is of the system.  Any independent proton cannot possess it's own potential energy .

Read this for more clarity: [Potential Energy](https://isaacphysics.org/concepts/cp_potential_energy)

Comment: When you now fix this proton you brought from infinity and let the other one go the change in kinetic energy is same therefore we can say the potential energy is of system

Answer (score 0):

Consider the well known formula for electrostatic potential energy $E={q_1 q_2 \over 4 \pi \epsilon_0 r_{12}}$

This does not `belong to' either particle 1 or particle 2. It is not even shared between them. Without *both* particles there is no potential energy.

So in your example the PE is not the PE of the proton but the PE of the pair of protons.  Of the system, if you like.

Even the potential energy   $mgh$ of, say, an apple is a joint energy of the apple and the earth, though one can usually get away with thinking of it as just a property of the apple as the influence of the earth on the apple is so much greater than the influence of the apple on the earth.